# Powershell: Azcopy a folder structure from the local drive to the blob storage

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

Hello I am new to azure portal and powershell.

I am trying to copy a local drive to the blob storage while maintaining the folder structure. Also it will be nice to have a manifest file which also gives me a list of folders and list of files in each.

Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: from `az copy --help` we can see: `azcopy cp "/path/to/dir" "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]" --recursive=true`. Did you try that?

Comment: I used  .\AzCopy /Source:$source /Dest:$blobURL /DestKey:$key /S it seems to copy everything from the filepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Azcopy to upload directory, we can use the following script. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#upload-a-directory)

```
azcopy copy "E:\sampleData" "https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>?<sasToken>" --recursive
```

[image]

Besides, you also can use the following PowerShell script to do that

```
$StorageAccountKey=" "
$sourceFileRootDirectory=" "
$StorageAccountName=" "
$ContainerName=" "
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $ctx

 if ($container) {
        $filesToUpload = Get-ChildItem $sourceFileRootDirectory -Recurse -File

        foreach ($x in $filesToUpload) {
            $blobName = ($x.fullname.Substring($x.PSDrive.Root.Length)).Replace("\", "/")

            Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $x.fullname -Container $container.Name -Blob $blobName -Context $ctx -Force:$Force 
        }
}
```

Comment: How can I output and save a verbose or manifest  which gives me a list of folders and list of files in each. 

From the azcopy tutorial I saw he used

.\Azcopy /source:C:files /Dest:blobURL /DestKey:$Key /S /V:\logs\AZCopyLogs.log

Is there another way in azcopy or from a powershell script that does manifest or verbose